# CASE, IF after where clause

Tags: sql, reporting-services, case, where-clause

Good Evening I hope someone can help me ( I have been working on this for 4 days)

I been working with a SQL database and Report Builder trying to figure out how to code this parameter after the where clause.

I have a parameter called @Active that is an int and takes the values of 0,1, and 3.  In the column in the table is called IsActive only has 2 values 0 meaning not active and 1 meaning active.  I asked the users to either choose active, not active or both for reporting purposes.

After the where clause I use the statement where

```
IsActive = (CASE WHEN @Active between 0 and 1 THEN @Active ELSE ??? END)
```

this is where I get stuck.

I cannot seem to get this report running with all cases.
I want to put after the Else `IsActive >= 0` but it errors out, so the report returns both active and not active data.  Can someone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Case When`.

- The first condition will take care of Active (1) or Inactive (0)
- and the second condition will take care of both.

The following clause will work for you.

```
(isActive = @Active or @Active = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to apply multiple conditions to a CASE statement, you would do that as follows:

```
CASE 
  WHEN @Active >= 0 and @Active <= 1 THEN @Active
  WHEN @Active >= 0 THEN [put some other value here]
  ELSE [put your catchall value here]
END
```

Hope that helps.